# Why my jupyter notebook showing "An Error Occured" on github?

Tags: github, jupyter

Can anyone suggest to me some fix for the following error?

[image: the error I'm getting]

Last night I uploaded my notebook and it was working fine. This morning I again uploaded the latest version of the same notebook and it's showing the above error.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common error and it can be resolved by simply retrying. I know this won't make it go away each time, but it can be useful if you desperately want to open it.

Another solution I see sometimes is to use https://nbviewer.org/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I cleared cache in browser and ran and saved the notebook again and uploaded it directly on github from the browser and it is working now.  Nb viewer is still out of date for me though so still having issues not sure if it's github or on my side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).